# Release Event Handler?

Tags: ios, events, release, handler

Maybe I'm just over thinking this, but is there a way to capture when the user let's go of a button with iOS? So to pose my question better: I have a button on the screen, and when the user let's go of it, I want to call an event. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: I know how to programmatically and in IB set up other events but I'm wondering how I can call a method when the user is touching, then let's go of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to answer, I wonder the same idea too..

From Apple Document : UIControl Class
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html

My Idea sub-class UI Control using following Task :

– beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:

– continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:

– endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:

– cancelTrackingWithEvent:

Put a BOOL isBegin = YES at beginTrackingWithTouch to know that it was touched.. 
Then when endTrackingWithTouch happen (which is the user end touching the control), do what you going to do in there then set isBegin back to NO

regards,

FHW